# Wrapping the iOS triple buffering procedure in a generic swift class

Tags: swift, pointers

In the Metal sample code and best practices guides it is advised to use a triple buffering technique to avoid access conflicts between the cpu and the gpu.

The required code to do so requires knowledge of data alignment which can be tricky to understand and involves some extra fields. I wanted to make it easier to create a triple buffer scheme for any data type so I created the following class.

It makes it simple to do this technique on any data type using only one field.

An example of how to use it is found on my [github](https://github.com/CalebKierum/Multi-Buffer-Access-Management). In most cases the constructor would be passed a maxBuffers value of 3.

I suppose I am hoping that the following things would be reviewed. This is my first time working with pointers in swift so I may have made some critical errors.

1. Is the pointer creation and management efficient?
2. Does the code sucesfully make sure that only one chunk of memory is claimed by the cpu at one setting
3. Is there a better way I can update the buffer? It would be nice to say BasicMB = myNewData however swift cant work that way. It would be at least nice to have a method where they don't have to initialize an object outside of the array.

Here is the code:

```
 class BasicMB<T>
 {
    //iOS is safe with offsets of a multiple of 16 bytes however MacOS requires multiples of 256 bytes
    #if os(iOS)
    private let idealOffset = 16
    #else
    private let idealOffset = 256
    #endif

    private var deviceBuffer:MTLBuffer


    private var bufferIndex:Int = 0
    private var bufferOffset:Int = 0
    private let maxBuffers:Int
    private let byteAllignedSize:Int
    private let arrayCount:Int

    //You can directly edit the data with .data[0] unexpected behavior will occur if you do anything else
    var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
    private var type: T.Type




    //Creates a multibuffer with maxBuffers slots taking count items per slot. Pass in MTLDevice to increase efficiency
    init?(dataType: T.Type, maxBuffers: Int, count: Int, device: MTLDevice?)
    {
        assert(count > 0, "Cant have a count of 0! There would be no data")

        self.maxBuffers = maxBuffers
        self.type = dataType
        arrayCount = count

        //If given a device use it otherwise make one
        var actualDevice = device
        if (actualDevice == nil)
        {actualDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()}

        //Round up to the nearest idealOffset multiple
        byteAllignedSize = (((MemoryLayout<T>.size * count) + (idealOffset - 1)) / (idealOffset)) * (idealOffset)

        guard let buffer = actualDevice!.makeBuffer(length:byteAllignedSize * maxBuffers, options:[MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared]) else { return nil }
        deviceBuffer = buffer

        data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(deviceBuffer.contents()).bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:count)
    }

    //After the semaphore has triggered you are free to switch the CPU writing location
    func prepareForUpdatePostSemaphore()
    {
        bufferIndex = (bufferIndex + 1) % maxBuffers
        bufferOffset = byteAllignedSize * bufferIndex

        data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(deviceBuffer.contents() + bufferOffset).bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:arrayCount)
    }

    //This is an acceptable way to update data in the buffer although you would be advised to use create your own class specefic to the type you are working wtih
    func update(dataIn: T, index: Int = 0)
    {
        data[index] = dataIn
    }

    //Avoid running in release builds
    func reportAllValues()
    {
        let save = bufferOffset

        var string = ""
        for i in 0..<maxBuffers
        {
            bufferOffset = byteAllignedSize * i
            data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(deviceBuffer.contents() + bufferOffset).bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:arrayCount)
            string += "|"
            for p in 0..<arrayCount
            {
                string += String.init(describing: data[p])
                string += " "
            }
            string += "|"
        }
        print(string)

        bufferOffset = save
        data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(deviceBuffer.contents() + bufferOffset).bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:arrayCount)
    }

    func buffer() -> MTLBuffer {
        return deviceBuffer
    }
    func offset() -> Int {
        return bufferOffset
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your platform-dependent code

> ```
> //iOS is safe with offsets of a multiple of 16 bytes however MacOS requires multiples of 256 bytes
> #if os(iOS)
> private let idealOffset = 16
> #else
> private let idealOffset = 256
> #endif
> ```

assumes that macOS and iOS are the only available platforms. 
But MetalKit is available on at least one more platform (tvOS),
and new platforms may be defined in the future.

Even it you only intend to use this class on iOS and macOS, better
check explicitly for this platforms

```
#if os(iOS)
private let idealOffset = 16
#elseif os(macOS)
private let idealOffset = 256
#endif
```

This forces you to think about the right value if the code is
compiled for another platform.

---

Your class defines two private properties with public getter methods:

> ```
> class BasicMB<T> {
>     private var deviceBuffer:MTLBuffer
>     private var bufferOffset:Int = 0
>
>     // ...
>
>     func buffer() -> MTLBuffer {
>         return deviceBuffer
>     }
>     func offset() -> Int {
>         return bufferOffset
>     }
> }
> ```

The same can be achieved with a public-readonly/private-readwrite
property:

```
class BasicMBx<T> {
    public private(set) var buffer: MTLBuffer
    public private(set) var offset: Int = 0

    // ...
}
```

Defining custom accessor methods is quite often not necessary in Swift.

---

This

> ```
>     //If given a device use it otherwise make one
>     var actualDevice = device
>     if (actualDevice == nil)
>     {actualDevice = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()}
> ```

is better and simpler done with the nil-coalescing operator `??`:

```
    // If given a device use it otherwise make one
    let actualDevice = device ?? MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
```

If you add a default value to the initializer

```
init?(dataType: T.Type, maxBuffers: Int, count: Int, device: MTLDevice? = nil) { ... }
```

then it can be called without a device instead of passing `nil`:

```
guard let mb = BasicMB(dataType: Int.self, maxBuffers: 3, count: 5) else { ... }
```

---

The conversion to `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` in

> ```
> data = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(deviceBuffer.contents()).bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:count)
> ```

is not needed because `deviceBuffer.contents()` already returns an
`UnsafeMutableRawPointer`:

```
data = deviceBuffer.contents().bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:count)
```

---

This

> ```
> func update(dataIn: T, index: Int = 0)
> {
>     data[index] = dataIn
> }
> ```

is more Swiftily done as a subscript operator:

```
subscript(index: Int) -> T {
    get {
        return data[index]
    }
    set {
        data[index] = newValue
    }
}
```

which is then used as

```
mb[0] = 1
```

A possible alternative would be to expose a view to the currently used
buffer area as an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`:

```
var currentBuffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<T> {
    return UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: deviceBuffer.contents().bindMemory(to:type.self, capacity:arrayCount), count: arrayCount)
}
```

---

The

> ```
> //Avoid running in release builds
> func reportAllValues() { ... }
> ```

is apparently meant for debugging, and that is what the 
`CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocol is for in Swift

```
extension BasicMB: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var debugDescription: String {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Then `debugPrint(mb)` prints the debug description.